# Git push hangs after writing a few files

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I was trying to push a a branch but it hangs after writing 82% of the objects. It doesn't proceed to write anything after 72 of 87 files but the corresponding file size increases and eventually exceeds the size of the whole project. what is the problem?

Writing objects:  82% (72/87), 4.09 MiB | 89 KiB/s

Comment: @CharlesB - the connection is fine.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but you're not tracking a bottomless file like `/dev/zero` are you?

Comment: @AndrewMyers - there is no file I explicitly untracked

Comment: @DonQuixote What do did you mean exceeds the size of the whole project?  Does it exceed the size of your working copy or the size of your working .git directory?

Comment: @AndrewMyers - the working copy.

Comment: @DonQuixote Was something large committed to the repository and then removed?  It could be pushing something that was in a prior commit but was deleted from the current head.

Comment: @AndrewMyers - yes there was. A video

Comment: Ah, that's it then, it's pushing the commit(s) containing the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in the comments there is a video in the commit history.  Any commit with the video is going to be huge, but should only need to be pushed once.  If you're okay with that then I would just wait for the push to complete.

If you need to remove it you'll have to rewrite your history to not contain the video.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872700/166732) has instructions on how to do this.  You can  use rebase if there are only a few commits, if not you should use `git filter-branch`.